# How does order work?

Tags: r, sorting

This is a very embarrassing question, but I cannot understand the result of the following:

```
> order(c(3,1,2))
[1] 2 3 1
```

So, it's saying the ordered sequence is `2, 3, 1`? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> a <- c(30,10,20)     # sample data
> sort(a)              # sort returns your vector sorted
[1] 10 20 33
> order(a)             # order returns the *indices* in the sorted vector
[1] 2 3 1
> a[order(a)]          # so if you select your numbers with those indices
[1] 10 20 30           # you get your vector sorted
```

Comment: How can this be extended to dataframes? I am having trouble using order to sort a table based on two columns

Comment: @Kory You can use `order` with several parameters. It'll sort w.r.t. to the first one, then the second one, etc. For instance, `df[order(df$a, df$b),]` will sort by column `a` and then by column `b`.